# Tensorflow Nueral Network not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

thank you for considering answering my question. I have a problem using TensorFlow where which I input my data and I keep getting the output:

```
('Epoch ', 0, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 1, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 2, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 3, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 4, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 5, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 6, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 7, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 8, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Epoch ', 9, ' completed out of ', 10, 'loss:', nan)
('Accuracy:', 1.0)
```

My X_train data is a 500 by 1000 matrix where each row consist of numbers such as:

```
-0.38484444, 1.4542222222 ...
```

I hope you get the idea...
And my Y_train data consists of binary classifications (0, 1).
len(X_train[0]) returns 1000, which is the amount of samples (columns)

I'm not too sure what else I need to make clear about my problem; I'm going to include my simple TensorFlow code, and please, if you need any more clarification about my code or problem please let me know.

Thank you for your time

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

da = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
ta = pd.read_csv("BMI.csv")

X_data = da.iloc[:, :1000]
Y_data = np.expand_dims(ta.iloc[:, -1], axis = 1)

X_train = X_data.iloc[:500 :,]
X_test = X_data.iloc[500:,:]

Y_train = Y_data[:500 :,]
Y_test = Y_data[735:,:]


X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 1
batch_size = 10

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, len(X_train[0])])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(X_train[0]), n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train_nueral_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            i = 0
            while i < len(X_train[0]):
                start = i
                end = i + batch_size

                batch_x = np.array(X_train[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(Y_train[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i += batch_size


            print('Epoch ', epoch, ' completed out of ', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:X_test, y:Y_test}))


train_nueral_network(x)
```

Comment: Can you please print and attach few lines of batch_y?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the tf.nn.relu with tf.nn.tanh and train it again, and check whether you would get the same results. Sometimes, ReLU induces the vanishing gradient problem.

https://ayearofai.com/rohan-4-the-vanishing-gradient-problem-ec68f76ffb9b

Comment: Hello and thanks for finding my question. I've replaced and unfortunately I'm getting the same results

Comment: Can you print the prediction and check?

Comment: I'm not familiar in how to print Tensor objects, and what variable did you want me to print?

Answer (score 0):

Your `n_classes=1`. Thus, you apply softmax on top of a single neuron which should always evaluate to 1. You should set `n_classes=2`.

In addition, in the current setting, the accuracy evaluation you use will always be 100% correct:

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
```

This is because both `prediction` and `y` are of shape `(BATCH_SIZE,1)` so argmax will always result to 0 for all samples.

I would advice to represent `y` in a one hot representation. Once you do it, the rest of your code should work.